# Composite Run Steps GitHub Actions error: 'An action could not be found at the URI'

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to use a composite run steps action on GitHub Actions, as described [here](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-08-07-github-actions-composite-run-steps/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20now%20create%20reusable,reuse%20them%20for%20different%20workflows.), in order to reuse them in different workflows.
However, I am getting the error:

```
An action could not be found at the URI 'https://api.github.com/repos/scripts/build_ubuntu/tarball/v1
```

My main workflow (`.github/workflows/BuildUbuntu.yml`) is the following:

```
[...]

jobs:
  ubuntu_build_appimage:
    name: Build MeshLab (Ubuntu - AppImage)
    runs-on: ubuntu-16.04

    steps:
    - uses: scripts/build_ubuntu@v1

[...]
```

And the composite step (`.github/workflows/scripts/build_ubuntu/action.yml`) is the following:

```
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps: 
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      submodules: true

  [other steps...]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here are the links:
[GitHub Commit](https://github.com/alemuntoni/meshlab/commit/fb3c3591ff93f5a49d590a735d672add38874b98) [Workflow](https://github.com/alemuntoni/meshlab/runs/1031019201?check_suite_focus=true)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your **workflow** is referencing the action incorrectly. It's looking for the repository `build_ubuntu` of the user / organization `scripts` with the tag `v1`.

You can reference it locally, because it is in the same repository.

```
[...]

jobs:
  ubuntu_build_appimage:
    name: Build MeshLab (Ubuntu - AppImage)
    runs-on: ubuntu-16.04

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: ./.github/workflows/scripts/build_ubuntu

[...]
```

Your **action** is missing the `name` and `description` elements. These are required as per https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions.

In addition, you can't use the `uses` step in a composite run steps action as [webknjaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/595220/webknjaz) noted in his comment. Currently you can only use `run` steps with the following subelements

> #### What does composite run steps currently support?
>
> For each run step in a composite action, we support:
>
> - name
> - id
> - run
> - env
> - shell
> - working-directory
>
> In addition, we support mapping input and outputs throughout the action.
> [...]
>
> #### What does Composite Run Steps Not Support
>
> We don't support setting conditionals, continue-on-error, timeout-minutes, "uses", and secrets on individual steps within a composite action right now.
>
> (Note: we do support these attributes being set in workflows for a step that uses a composite run steps action)

(source: https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/646)

```
name: "My composite action"
description: "Execute some run setps to do something"
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps: 
  - run: |
      echo do something
      echo and do something else

  [other steps...]
```

Comment: https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/646 seems to imply that `uses` isn't supported at the moment.

Comment: This has now changed: https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-25-github-actions-reduce-duplication-with-action-composition/
It, however, only supports nested `uses` and not nested `job`s