# How to run multiple GitHub Actions workflows from sub directories

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions

I have 3 directories in `./github/workflows/`

- linters
- functionalTests
- unitTests

In each of these directories I have multiple workflow `.yml` files for example in `linters/codeQuality.yml`

My issue is that when a pull request is made then only the workflows files in root are executed and not the workflow files in these diretories.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I am wondering the same.

Answer (score 10):

You can't run workflows from subdirectories:

> You must store workflow files in the `.github/workflows` directory of your repository.

Source:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#about-yaml-syntax-for-workflows

---

You can however use *composite run steps actions* ([documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-run-steps-action#creating-an-action-metadata-file)).

`.github/workflows/workflow.yaml`

```
[...]

jobs:
  myJob:
    name: My Job
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: ./.github/workflows/linters/codeQuality

[...]
```

`.github/workflows/linters/codeQuality/action.yaml`

```
name: "My composite action"
description: "Checks out the repository and does something"
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps: 
  - run: |
      echo "Doing something"

  [other steps...]
```

Comment: Okay. Is there a way that I can call the workflows from the main workflow file ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63710170 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/63606663

Comment: This did not helped me

Comment: How do we know which workflow runs in which order?