# Github actions : calling mutliple yaml inside a yaml

Tags: github, continuous-integration, yaml, workflow, github-actions

I have a quite similar question than user989988 aked [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64055230/nested-templates-calling-a-yaml-file-from-another-yaml-file-in-github-actions)

Is it possible to call some yaml files from inside a workflow in Github actions?

This would be something like that :

```
name: my test
on:
    workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
    first-job:
         runs-on: my_server
         strategy:  
             fail-fast: false
         env:
             my_results: "my results"
         steps:
             - uses: one.yaml
             - name: my shell
               run: |
                  ... do some stuf there
     second-job:
          runs-on: my_server2
          steps:
              - uses: two.yaml
...
```

That stuff would be useful to reuse some yaml files from one workflow to another one!

Thank you for your response!

Comment: You can now call local composite actions, that are composed of `action.yml` files, inside the same repository, using for exemple this syntax: `uses: ./.github/actions/local-action`. Here is a personal example if you want to take a look: [workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/36-local-action.yml) + [local action.yml file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/tree/main/.github/actions/local-action). There is no limit to the amount of folder you could use that way in the same repository and workflow.

Comment: Besides, this solution is explained in one of the answer of the question you shared :)

Comment: yes, but i was wondering if there was another way to do that now :)